# How to modify variables of a Java program using Javascript eval?

Tags: javascript, java

I want to modify the variables in a Java program using its inbuilt Javascript engine. Is this possible to do so ?

```
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

Integer x = new Integer(11);
Integer y = new Integer(20);

Bindings bindings = new SimpleBindings();       
bindings.put("x", x);
bindings.put("y", y);

engine.eval("if (x > 10) {" + 
            "   print(\"Entered condition\");" +
            "   y = 90;" + 
            "}", bindings);

System.out.println(bindings.get("y"));
```

The above prints 20.

Comment: Documentation of `eval`: "Executes the script using the Bindings argument as the ENGINE_SCOPE Bindings of the ScriptEngine during the script execution. The Reader, Writer and non-ENGINE_SCOPE Bindings of the default ScriptContext are used. The ENGINE_SCOPE Bindings of the ScriptEngine is **not** changed, and its mappings are unaltered by the script execution."

Comment: use `Bindings bindings = engine.createBindings();`